# How do I rewrite my method to return a list or Movie rather than a list of String?

Tags: java, android, methods

I have would like to rewrite my method so that it returns a List of Movie class rather than a list of String class, here's the method I want to change:

```
private List<String> getMovieDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr)
            throws JSONException {
        JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray("results");
        List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject movie = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
            urls.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + movie.getString("poster_path"));
        }
        return urls;
    }
```

I tried to rewrite it like this:

```
  private List<Movie> getMovieDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr)
                throws JSONException {
            JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray("results");
            List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject movie = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Movie movie1 = new Movie(movie.getString("original_title"), movie.getDouble("vote_average"), movie.getString("release_date"), movie.getString("overview"), movie.getString("poster_path"));
                movies.add(movie1);
            }
            return movies;
        }
```

But the problem is I'm getting error on line 139, it's saying required is String but found Movie instead. Here is  line 139:
 return getMovieDataFromJson(movieJsonStr);

Here is my code:

```
package com.projmobileapp.pmdbadd.pmdb;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    //ArrayAdapter<String> mMovieAdapter;
    //String[] movieId,movieTitle,movieOverview,movieReleaseDate,movieVoteAverage;
    String[] moviePosterPath = new String[0];

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity());
        GridView listView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_movie);
        listView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
        updateMovie();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainactivityfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            updateMovie();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void updateMovie() {
        FetchMovieTask movieTask = new FetchMovieTask();
        movieTask.execute();
    }

    class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMovieTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String movieJsonStr = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=INSERTAPIKEY");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                movieJsonStr = buffer.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                return getMovieDataFromJson(movieJsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException j) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "JSON Error", j);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private List<String> getMovieDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr)
                throws JSONException {
            JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray("results");
            List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject movie = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
                urls.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + movie.getString("poster_path"));
            }
            return urls;
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
            mMovieAdapter.replace(strings);
        }
    }

    class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final String LOG_TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
        private final Context context;
        private final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

        public MovieAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            Collections.addAll(urls, moviePosterPath);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = new ImageView(context);
            }
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;


            String url = getItem(position);

            Log.e(LOG_TAG, " URL " + url);

            Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return urls.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return urls.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public void replace(List<String> urls) {
            this.urls.clear();
            this.urls.addAll(urls);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your `AsyncTask` defines the result type for `doInBackground()` as `List<String>`. You need to change the line:

```
class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>
```

to

```
class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Movie>>
```

and change `doInBackground()` to return `List<Movie>`

Comment: thanks I did that and now its complaining about this line of code: @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
            mMovieAdapter.replace(strings);
        }

Comment: it's saying "method does not override or implement a method from supertype".

Comment: You also need to change `onPostExecute()` to take `List<Movie>` as an argument instead of `List<String>` - e.g. : `protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> movies)`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did that now it doesnt like the line inside the onPostExecute method:  mMovieAdapter.replace(strings);  it's saying method replace cannot be applied to a given type

Comment: You need to change your `onPostExecute()` to create a `List<String>` containing your URLs and then call `mMovieAdapter.replace()` with your new list of Strings, so you'll have to iterate through your `List<Movie>` creating the URLs and adding them to a list.

Comment: thanks could you elaborate what you mean?I changed my method to the following but this still not working :   @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> strings) {
            for(String movieStr : strings) {
                mMovieAdapter.replace(movieStr);
            }

        }

Comment: `@Override protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> movies) { List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>(); for(Movie movie : movies) { urls.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + movie.getPosterPath()); } mMovieAdapter.replace(urls); }` I've assumed you have a `getPosterPath()` method on your `Movie` class to get back the poster path you pass to the `Movie` constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84939/discussion-between-dragontbone-and-hexandbugs).